# Python Shell não consegue correr um módulo com mais de um while loop

Tags: python-3.x

Tenho graves problemas em conseguir construir um módulo funcional em que tenha de usar mais de 1 while loop, pois o programa deixa de correr.

Principalmente quando uso módulos como pygame e tkinter, em que o meu objetivo é construir um jogo, mas preciso de usar mais de 1 while loop, só que se o ponho a correr ele deixa de funcionar. Nesta situação pretendo correr dois while loops ao mesmo tempo, mas a janela deixa de responder. PorquÊ?

----------------------------#######--------------------------------------

Também não percebi porque é que o meu while loop não deixa de existir quando torno a variável 'playing' True? Nesta situação só quero correr um while loop de cada vez, sendo que o switch off do while loop é quando a variável 'playing' fica True. Eis o código:

```
playing = False
def play():
    playing = True

def gameloop():
    ...
    play()

while not playing:
    gameloop()

while playing:
    gameDisplay.fill(black)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(15)
```

O problema é que o segundo while loop não corre e o primeiro não deixa de correr quando chamo a função play(), mesmo se declarar a variável 'playing' global. PorquÊ?

Usando python 3.5.0 com Windows 10

Não vejo motivos para as janelas deixaram de responder quando corro mais de um while loop, porque com os pc's das outras pessoas funciona perfeitamente. O problema será do meu pc?

Comment: Como assim "deixa de funcionar"? Descreva mais detalhadamente o comportamento observado.

Comment: Você quer deixar os dois laços executando em conjunto? Ou o ``while`` de baixo só deve ser iniciado quando ``playing`` for ``true``? Descreva melhor como diz o @PabloAlmeida.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida como estou a trabalhar com o tkinter a janela deixa de funcionar('não responde')

Comment: @ChristianFelipe Sim quero os dois loops ao mesmo tempo, mas só na segunda situação. E o while de baixo só deve ser iniciado quando playing for True

Comment: Mas na sua lógica, se o ``playing`` for True o while de cima acaba, então você terá só um while executando de toda forma.

Comment: @ChristianFelipe     pois mas quando corro o programa e torno a variável 'playing' True o while de cima não deixa de correr e o while de baixo não começa a correr

Answer (score 2):

O corre que quando você colocou:

```
def play():
    playing = True
```

O interpretador criou `playing` como uma variável local, então mesmo que altere o valor dentro de `play` o `playing` global permanecerá `False`.

### Declaração da variável global

Para dizer ao interpretador que deseja utilizar a variável global, deve-se passar o atributo `global` para a variável no método. Caso a variável não exista, ela é instanciada. Testado em **python3.4 (Gentoo Linux)**

```
def play():
    global playing
    playing = True
```

Ao contrario do que muitos iniciantes acham, para usar uma variável global não basta apenas declará-la no topo do arquivo, precisa especificar no método que usará uma variável global.

Caso não funcione, é possível usar métodos alternativos.

### Biblioteca

**vars.py:**

```
playing = False
```

**main.py:**

```
import vars

...

def play():
    playing = True

...

while not vars.playing:
    ...
```

Esse método, importa as variáveis de um arquivo python, assim quando faz a referencia a variável, é passado o caminho dela assim o método não cria uma variável local.

### Static

```
def gameloop():
    self.playing = True
gameloop.playing = False

...

while not gameloop.playing:
```

### Dict

```
conf = {
    'playing' : False,
}

def play():
    conf['playing'] = True

...

while not conf['playing']:
    ...
```

Comment: Mas para tornar a variável global, só preciso de usar o atributo 'global' e declarar a variável global, não? O que já tentei fazer mas não resulta na mesma

Comment: @InêsBarataFeioBorges, acrescentei um trecho com a declaração da variável global dentro de `play`. O teste funcionou no meu computador, mas se o erro persistir, tente rodar o código em outra versão do python ou em uma maquina virtual com outro SO. as vezes pode ser algum erro no interpretador